# Выравнивание кода в Atom

Tags: atom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за сочетание клавиш или плагин для выравнивания кода в редакторе Atom на mac (выравнивание нескольких строк с переменными по знаку равно).

[image: примр кода]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов например из них:
https://atom.io/packages/atom-alignment
https://atom.io/packages/aligner

Comment: Спасибо, попробую в работе.

Answer (score 3):

[Тут](http://unetway.com/blog/kak-sdelat-avtomaticeskoe-vyravnivanie-koda-v-atom/) всё понятно описано.

В редакторе Atom для этого нужно в верхнем меню выбрать Edit - Lines - Auto Indent. Так как у этой опции нет установленного сочетания клавиш, то чтобы добавить их, нужно в верхнем меню выбрать File - Keymap и в открывшемся файле редактора написать следующее:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-a': 'editor:auto-indent'
```

Где <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>a</kbd> - сочетания клавиш для автоматического выравнивания кода. После этого, изменения нужно сохранить.

Теперь остается только выделить весь код (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>a</kbd>).

Затем нажать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>a</kbd>.